# Why doesn't my disk get shared via NFS?

Tags: mount, nfs

I have had no problems getting NFS to work until now. I'm trying to mount an internal disk `/dev/disk` under a certain location, `/location/disk`, then share that location with another machine by exporting `/location`.

When I mount `/location` on the other machine though, it doesn't see `disk/`

When I make a regular file in `/location`, it shows up on the other machine.

Why doesn't the disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is apparently normal behavior for NFS. Mounted file systems are not re-exported automatically. You must explicitly export the mounted filesystem in `/etc/exports` on the server:

```
/location/disk           clientMachine(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,no_root_squash)
```

Don't forget to `sudo exportfs -ra` on the server, then unmount and re-mount `/location` on the client.

See also: [this unix.stackexchange question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/278986/how-can-i-share-an-internal-disk-via-nfs-what-am-i-doing-wrong/278990#278990)

Comment: you should not use no_root_squash because root can then from other machine can access all your shared files. This is a big security hole

Comment: It would be better if you also enable kerbose theree